# Rider - I can't start a project if there are uploaded projects

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

I'm using JetBrains Rider, and I have a problem: I have a lot of projects and they all show up in the startup configuration, even when I clicked "Unload projects" and unloaded them, because of this, I can't find the project I need to run, and I can't run any project because I'm being prevented these unloaded projects are in the startup configuration and this error appears (see below), while in Visual Studio the unloaded projects are not displayed in the startup configuration.

How do I also do in Rider so that the unloaded projects are not displayed in the startup configuration, and only the downloaded projects are displayed there?

> Error: Error running 'Topic1: IIS Express': Project C:/Users/rinsh/RiderProjects/MetanitASPLearning/Chapter2Topic5Project1/Chapter2Topic5Project1.csproj not found in the solution, reason: JetBrains.Diagnostics.Assertion+AssertionException: Project C:/Users/rinsh/RiderProjects/MetanitASPLearning/Chapter2Topic5Project1/Chapter2Topic5Project1.csproj not found in the solution in JetBrains.Diagnostics.Assertion.Fail(String message) in JetBrains.Rider.Backend.Features.IisIntegration.IisExpressHost.GetDefaultAncmHostingModel(RdAncmHostingModelRequest request) in JetBrains.Rd.Tasks.RdTaskEx.c__DisplayClass8_0`2. b__0(Lifetime _, TReq req) in JetBrains.Rd.Tasks.RdCall`2.OnWireReceived(UnsafeReader reader)

I looked through the settings, and tried to change the configuration settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you mind contacting Rider support directly regarding this case? You can contact support via **Help | Contact Support**. Please, attach your project and a full-screen screenshot that demonstrates the issue.

Meanwhile, you might want to try the following:
Unload all the projects by right-clicking on solution in explorer and selecting "Unload projects". Then find the exact project you need, right-click on it and select "Load Project with Dependencies".

Hope that helps.

Have a nice day!